# How to get object to use in v-bind, in v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Consider:

```html
<ol class="breadcrumb arr-right">
    <li v-for="(url,name, index) in links" v-bind:class=" (index == (links.length -1)) ? 'breadcrumb-item active' : 'breadcrumb-item'">
        <a v-bind:href="url">{{ name }}</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

The problem here is `links.length` is always `undefined`.  Everything in this works fine except the ternary operation due to the `undefined` state of links.  How do I access `links` from `v-bind`?

Comment: When you bind a class, you should use an object. So, wrap your ternary with { }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `links` is an `object`, `links.length` will always be `undefined` because an `object` doesn't have a `length` property (but an `Array` [does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)).

You can determine the size of the `object` by its key length. Note that [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) gives an `Array` of the `object`'s keys, so you could use `Array.prototype.length` on the result to get the object size.

```js
const class = index === Object.keys(links).length - 1
            ? 'breadcrumb-item active'
            : 'breadcrumb-item'
```

The syntax for your [class binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) is not quite correct.
You could combine [object syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax) and [array syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax) like this:

```html
<li v-bind:class="[ { 'active': index === Object.keys(links).length - 1 }, 'breadcrumb-item' ]">
```

[demo 1](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/pBvQWY?editors=1010)

Or just use object syntax:

```html
<li class="breadcrumb-item" v-bind:class="{ 'active': index === Object.keys(links).length - 1 }">
```

[demo 2](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/axzQVv?editors=1010)

But if your objective is to style the last `<li>` element, there might be a simpler way in CSS. Instead of applying `.breadcrumb-item.active` to the last item, use [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type):

```css
.breadcrumb-item:last-of-type {
  /* your styles here */
}
```

[demo 3](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/axzQVv)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb arr-right">
    <li v-for="(item, index) in links" v-bind:class=" (index == (links.length -1)) ? 'breadcrumb-item active' : 'breadcrumb-item'">
        <a v-bind:href="item.url">{{ item.name }}</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  Here is the json of the links data:

{ "United States": "https://new.mysite.com", "Arizona": "https://new.mysite.com.com/regions/arizona" }

Comment: That is not a valid JSON array. A valid one should look something like this: [{'name': 'United States', url: 'new.mysite.com'}, {'name': 'Arizona', url: 'new.mysite.com/regions/arizona'}, {...}]

Comment: This is what it looks like what I just spit it out in view {{ links }}  Not the actual json array itself..

Comment: In that case, use may need to do a JSON.parse(links) and assign it to a variable first.